# Running an exported Xtend based application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtend

I am attempting to use Xtend to generate and run an exported Eclipse RCP application. I am using Windows 10 with Java 1.8.0_181 and Eclipse Photon.

The following steps will recreate the problem in as clean an environment as I can create:

- Install Eclipse Photon using the advanced mode of Oomph

  - Control the location of the pool so it will not inadvertently clobbered by other Eclipse usage.
  - Ensure that Java 8 is used for Eclipse
- Create a new Eclipse workspace with the following configuration:

  - PDE stores the runtime files in a separate part of the workspace
  - The complete Xtext SDK is installed
- Create an Eclipse plugin project with the following attributes:

  - Creates a RCP application
  - Uses the Eclipse E4 application template to seed the project
  - Includes the optionally generated graphic components
  - Convert the generated Java files to Xtend and get rid of the original Java files.
  - Load the generated product configuration and run the application from the Overview page. This works without problem.
  - Export the project using the export wizard from the product configuration page. The export runs without any reported errors.
  - Start the exported project from the command line. It fails in the following manner:
  - The application comes up but none of the components supplied by the Xtend code are displayed.
  - Here is the log from the run:

```
 !SESSION 2018-07-26 13:03:49.115 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_181
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-26 13:03:50.733
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.QuitHandler' from bundle '2'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.QuitHandler cannot be found by com.example.e4.rcp.wizard_1.0.0.201807261104
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.processActiveHandler(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.postConstruct(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-26 13:03:50.740
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.OpenHandler' from bundle '2'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.OpenHandler cannot be found by com.example.e4.rcp.wizard_1.0.0.201807261104
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.processActiveHandler(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.postConstruct(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-26 13:03:50.745
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.SaveHandler' from bundle '2'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.SaveHandler cannot be found by com.example.e4.rcp.wizard_1.0.0.201807261104
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.processActiveHandler(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.postConstruct(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-26 13:03:50.750
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.AboutHandler' from bundle '2'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.handlers.AboutHandler cannot be found by com.example.e4.rcp.wizard_1.0.0.201807261104
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.processActiveHandler(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.postConstruct(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-07-26 13:03:51.148
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.parts.SamplePart' from bundle '2'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.parts.SamplePart cannot be found by com.example.e4.rcp.wizard_1.0.0.201807261104
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1277)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4567)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)


- As you can see none of the classes specified in the Xtend files could be found. It appears that the reason for this that the jar file containing the project artifacts (in the exported plugins directory) only contains the Xtend source code, not the Java .class files that I believe are needed.
```

I have added the build.properties file as generated by Eclipse. I did not touch it.

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/,\
               css/default.css,\
               Application.e4xmi
```

What do I need to do to get a correct exported jar file for the project?

Comment: how do your build.properties files look like?

Comment: @Christian Dietrich  I added the build.properties file to the end of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make sure that the xtend-gen folder is a source folder and listed in the `build.properties` file. you should even get a warning on it.

[image: Before]

and after

```
source.. = src/,\
       xtend-gen/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
...
               .
```

and here the .classpath that adds xtend-gen as source folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="xtend-gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```